# Printf a double

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I have a problem in printing a `double` in C.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
   double n;
   scanf("%lf", &n);
   printf("%f", n);
}
```

input: `446486416781684178`

output: `446486416781684160`

Why does the number change ?

Comment: Floating point types can only store up to, I think it was 2^53 for 64-Bit doubles, until the minimal difference between one double value and the very next representable value becomes >1, thus possibly being unable to represent the value you entered exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Using a `long double`  would give you extra bits of precision if you really need it. `long double n = 446486416781684178; printf("%Lf", n);`

Comment: @PhilMasteG the number i chose is less than 2^53 .

Comment: @TedLyngmo when i use this i get a problem that the number printed becomes 0 .

Comment: @Rim the number you chose needs 59 bits. `0x` `0632` `3D07` `CD4F` `2DD2`

Comment: @Rim It [looks ok to me](https://godbolt.org/z/jc9v6Edr9)

Comment: @TedLyngmo i want to use it with a `scanf` . i 've used `scanf("%LF",&n)` is this correct ?

Comment: @Rim Yes, that's correct and [works](https://godbolt.org/z/Y6aEqh5az)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo That's exectly what i've done and it the result printed out was 0.          
   `long double n;
    scanf("%Lf",&n);
    printf("%Lf",n);`

Comment: Always check that scanf succeeds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i'm sorry i'm a beginner to C; How am i supposed to do that ?

Comment: @Rim Like I did.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have exactly used the same code as yours and it didn't work . (I'm working with codeblocks).

Comment: _"didn't work"_ - as in, it still printed `0` or it didn't print anything (meaning that `scanf` failed)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo i used the same code you have used and it printed out a 0 .

Comment: @Rim That sounds like a bug. What compiler and compiler version are you using?

Answer (score 5):

The number you entered can't be represented exactly in a `double`.

Typically, a `double` is represented using IEEE754 double precision format.  This format can hold up to 53 bits of precision.  The value you entered requires 58 bits of precision.  So what is stored is either the next or the previous representable value.

Comment: is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: @Rim A `long long` can hold this value, however it depends on exactly how you want to use it.

Comment: There is `long double` but MSVC still has not implemented it (it's just `double`) even in their 2022 compiler version.

Comment: Actually, the C17 standard does not even dictate `long double` to be bigger than `double`, so it's up to MS to integrate bigger `long double`s into MSVC or not.

Comment: @Rim: If you need to represent and do arithmetic operations on large numbers (>16 decimal digits), you may want to look at a third-party arbitrary precision library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or similar.  Native floating point types are limited.

Comment: @dbush   i'm sorry i'm a beginner to C ; how can i `scanf` and `printf` this `long long` type ?

Comment: @Rim: Use `%lld` for both `printf` and `scanf`; remember that `long long` is an integer type, not floating point.

Comment: @Rim *is there a solution to this problem?* If you mean, the problem that some numbers can't be represented, no.  It's a pretty fundamental problem, that we have to accept and live with.  Ordinary types have finite range and, in the case of floating point, finite precision.  You cannot store the number 1234567890123456789012 in an `int`: It just won't fit.  You cannot store the number 0.0000000001 in a `float`: It's too small.  Those are both pretty obvious.  A little harder to think about is that there are ordinary-looking integers that you can't store as type `float` or `double`, either.

Comment: The concept of "precision" doesn't just refer to the right of the decimal point: precision can be an issue to the left of the decimal point, also.  And your number 446486416781684178 is a perfect example.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the number change?

It got rounded off, because type `double` has finite precision.

We're used to roundoff happening to the right of the decimal point.  If we write

```
double d = 0.123456789012345678;
printf("%.18f\n", d);
```

we are not too surprised if it prints

```
0.123456789012345677
```

Type `double` has the equivalent of about 16 decimal digit's worth of precision (actually it's more complicated than that), so it definitely can't represent all 18 digits of that number 0.123456789012345678.

But your number 446486416781684178 also has 18 significant digits, so we can't be too surprised that it can't be represented exactly, either.  In other words, roundoff can happen to the *left* of the decimal point, also.

Internally, type `double` can represent numbers with 53 bits of precision.  That means it can represent integers up to 2<sup>53</sup>, or 9007199254740992, with perfect accuracy.  But bigger than that — it just can't!  It can represent 900...992, and it can represent 900...994, but if you try to do 900...993, it gets rounded back down to 900...992.  If we look at the binary representations of these and nearby numbers, we can see why:

| Decimal | Binary | Rep? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9007199254740990 | `11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110` | yes |
| 9007199254740991 | `11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` | yes |
| 9007199254740992 | `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` | yes |
| 9007199254740993 | `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001` | no |
| 9007199254740994 | `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010` | yes |

Since we only have 53 bits of significance, for a 54-bit number like 9007199254740992 or 9007199254740994, the 54th bit has to be 0, which basically means we can only represent even numbers in that range.  The 54-bit number 9007199254740993 ends with a 1 bit, so it can't be exactly represented, which I've indicated with a "no" in the "Rep" ("exactly representable") column.

When we get up to a 59-bit number like 446486416781684178, the last *six* bits have to be 0, which means we can only represent numbers which are a multiple of 2<sup>6</sup>, or 64:

| Decimal | Binary | Rep? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 446486416781684160 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111000000` | yes |
| 446486416781684161 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111000001` | no |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 446486416781684177 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111010001` | no |
| 446486416781684178 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111010010` | no |
| 446486416781684179 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111010011` | no |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 446486416781684223 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010110111111111` | no |
| 446486416781684224 | `1100011001000111101…001101010011110010111000000000` | yes |

Answer (score 1):

The number *changes* because of the limited precision of the `double` type. If you don't need floating point values, you could use type `long long` which is defined to have at least 63 value bits and can represent the number in the question.

Note that it is highly unlikely that the output be `446486416781684160`, the `printf("%f", n)` call should produce `446486416781684160.000000`. If your program does not produce 6 decimal places, your compiler and/or standard library are not conforming.

Also note that the `main` function should be defined with an explicit return type of `int`. The implicit `int` style has been deprecated more than 20 years ago.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long long n;
    if (scanf("%lld", &n) == 1) {
        printf("%lld\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `446486416781684178`
Output: `446486416781684178`